# How to make an option selected according to the value of an input given

Tags: jquery, laravel

In my DB table `sources` i have some sources with their url's.  im getting their values  using eloquent:

```
<?php $src = App\Source::orderBy("name", "ASC")->get()?>
<select class="form-control selectedSRC" name="sources">
  @foreach($src as $option)
    <option value="{{$option->id}}">{{$option->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

I have an input for a url:

```
<input class="sources col-md-3 srcURL" 
type="url" class="form-control"
name="sourcesUrl" placeholder="Source URL">
```

When I enter an url in the input, I want the name of the source to be selected by checking if the url of the source is contained within the url of the input. Ex:

```
input url: www.google.com/images/smiley.jpg
src in DB: www.google.com (with name: GOOGLE)
```

When I input the url above i want GOOGLE option to be selected

Comment: Why post PHP when you want a jQuery solution? Click the `<>` and post RENDERED html along with the jQuery you tried so far. Remember to click TIDY before saving the [mcve] - you want to look at `$(".srcURL").on("input",function() { something to look at the URL substring });`

Comment: To do this, I would first add a custom attribute to every option, containing the src url, then using javascript/jquery you can select the correct option by comparing the input url and the src url of every option.

Comment: And another thing, not sure if you did this, but in Laravel you should get your resources etc. in the controller, not in the view. From what I see here you are getting the Sources in the view which is not the recommended way to work.

Answer (score 1):

To do like that as you say above

First you have to change the select option
Like

```
   <?php $src = App\Source::orderBy("name", "ASC")->get()?>
    <select class="form-control selectedSRC" name="sources">
        @foreach($src as $option)
            <option value="{{$option->url}}">{{$option->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

Now Just add this Jquery to your page then it will work perfect.

```
$('.sources .col-md-3 .srcURL').on('change',function(){
        $(".form-control .selectedSRC").val($(this).val());    
    });
```